# Avoid passing around request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I am writing a React app (Express server) that renders on both the client + server using a shared ('isomorphic') codebase. In some cases, when the server is the renderer, I want to access the request object, without having to pass it around all over the place. Since node responds to one request at a time, isn't it safe to take advantage of caching the variable, making sure to reset it before sending response?

This works, but can someone tell me why it is either a good or a bad idea?...

*server.js*

```
var r = require('./request-store');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  r.set(req);
  next();
});

var resolve = require('./resolve');
// ...deferring to react router for client / server routing
app.use(function(req, res) {
  resolve().then(function(data) {
    r.set(null);
    res.render('index', { data: data });
  });
});
```

*request-store.js*

```
var r = null;
module.exports.set = function(req) { r = req; };
module.exports.get = function() { return r; };
```

*resolve.js*

```
var r = require('./request-store');
module.exports = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    if (isServer) {
      console.log(r.get());
      resolve();
    } else if (isClient) {
      resolve();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But what happens if you get two simultaneous requests from different users? The first request will get cached, and the second will overwrite the first user's request. Meanwhile suppose you were doing some IO and needed to access the request once it finished, then the first user's request object would have already been overwritten with the second user's request. Overall it's pretty dangerous to do it this way. The best way would be to use some sort of in memory key-value store, but you'd still need to somehow pass around the key.

Comment: If thats the case then yes that won't work. So is it possible for express to process another req before it issues a previous res?

Comment: Certainly, suppose you have a database query that takes seconds to process, since node is asynchronous, that db operation would not block the execution of subsequent requests.

Comment: Ok the way I was experimenting with this was multiple tabs open in Chrome, which apparently waits to issue next request to the same URL until the first one comes back. Thats why I was confused. Testing this with multiple browsers + apache bench I clearly see the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong, Node is *not* asynchronous, it's 100% synchronous - only I/O operations in Node are asynchronous (or non-blocking). It's not possible for the request to be overwritten before the other middleware runs *unless* there is an I/O operation in between. It doesn't matter if multiple requests come in from different clients, the V8 engine will queue up the requests and process them in order.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but irrelevant. What matters is that you program IO in node applications in an asynchronous manner and that each request is processed in the same thread, hence sharing memory. These are the two biggest areas that new developers coming from other platforms struggle with. I can modify my comment to say 'since node's IO operations are asynchronous' and my point would still stand.

Answer (score 2):

Given Node is single-threaded, and you don't *appear* to be performing any I/O, then yes your code looks safe to me. Express will run all the middleware synchronously therefore by the time your promise runs (as it's also synchronous) `r.get()` should return the correct request object.

However, I'm not sure you need to cache it at all, you could pass it directly into `resolve` and use a closure to capture it inside your promise

```
var resolve = require('./resolve');
// ...deferring to react router for client / server routing
app.use(function(req, res) {
    // pass 'req' into `resolve`
    resolve(req).then(function(data) {
        r.set(null);
        res.render('index', { data: data });
    });
});
```

*resolve.js*

```
var r = require('./request-store');
module.exports = function(req) {
  // capture 'req' for use later
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    if (isServer) {
      console.log(req);
      resolve();
    } else if (isClient) {
      resolve();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: nvm i saw an issue when i tried this w apache bench + concurrency

Comment: @ndreckshage saw what issue?

Comment: That multiple requests were happening at once. Experimented with setTimeout(resolve, 5000) in resolve.js, and console logged the request # + response #. Confusion because I hit the page in chrome in 10 tabs at once, and the requests/responses were logged in sequential order (req, res, req, res, req, res). Testing with apache bench + concurrency, I saw the requests all logged together (req, req, req, res, res, res).

Comment: That's because setTimeout makes the resolve call asynchronous (unlike your example above). If you ran the closure suggestion in my answer though it should give you the correct request, even with a setTimeout?